# Improper results - Load test for java rest api application

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

For a rest api application in java, we are planning to perform a load test. But the initial results are a bit confusing. Post development of script using jmeter. 
1. we execute the script for 1 vuser, 2 vusers, 5vuser, 10 vusers & 25vusers
2. Each test is executed for 30 minutes duration with nearly 5 sec rampup. 
3. Each request has a random think time from 2 sec to 3 sec.

When this test is executed we see that for for few apis the 95%ile response time for 2, 5, 10 vuser is way less than 1 vuser. But same test post restart of tomcat gives different results

I am confused as to how the response time is decreasing as vusers are increasing.

**Response time graphs, when tomcat instance is not restarted** : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaBYl.jpg

**Response time graphs, when tomcat instance is restarted** : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2HpI.jpg

Comment: Did you check that in all cases you get successful responses?

Comment: Yes, all the responses have 200,ok..

Answer (score 1):

There is one Java runtime feature: [Just-in-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), the [Java bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) gets translated into the native code after ~1500 invocations (default value), controllable via [-XX:CompileThreshold](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) property.

That could be the explanation for the situation you're facing: Java runtime optimizes the functions according to their usage hence function execution time might decrease if you repeatedly call it.

Also don't expect that response time for 2 virtual users will be 2x times higher than for 1 virtual user. The application might scale up to certain extent and when you increase the load the throughput will increase and the response time will remain the same.

At some point response time will start growing and throughput will go down and this is known as [performance bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing), however the chance you will hit application limits with 25 users is minimal given current modern hardware.

So consider applying the following performance testing types:

1. [Load testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing): start with 1 user and gradually increase the load till the anticipated amount of virtual users at the same time looking at throughput and response time. If you will not detect performance degradation as number of users is growing - you can report that the application is ready for production usage
2. [Stress testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing): start with 1 user and gradually increase the load until response time starts growing or errors start occurring. This will provide you information like what is the maximum number of users it can support and what is the component which will fail first.

More information: [Why ‘Normal’ Load Testing Isn’t Enough](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough/)

Comment: hi Dmitri, 
Thanks for comments. I have added the response time graphs in the question.
1. when we restart tomcat instance and execute the same test, the results are correct. i.e, when the vusers increases the response time also increase.
2. But when I perform the same test after 24 hours, withouth restarting tomcat instance, the results are bad. 

i will also add the memory graphs i collected during tests.

Also i monitored the GC, GC seems to be happening

Comment: the current hardware in prod is on AWS, medium one. i.e. we have 2 application servers having 1 core processor with ELB. ELB is round robin algorithm. But we have removed one of the nodes from ELB and executing the test

Answer (score 0):

Check that your API does not return 200 for invalid responses at scale.

Use ResponseAssertion for that.